# Understanding offscreen canvas to better performance

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs, offscreen-canvas

Hey everyone so I have a very complex canvas editor that allows a user to pick a video background, add text, gifs and Lottie animations using the Konvajs and Gifler libraries. It has come a long way however I am trying to speed up the performance of my canvas application. I've read a lot about offscreen canvas but I don't quite understand it. Say I have a regular HTML canvas object how would I create an offscreen canvas and spit that back out to the browser? I would ideally like to be able to get images from the canvas in an array at 30 fps with no latency. I also have another concern that offscreen canvas as of yet does not seem to be widely supported according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=offscreencanvas). Whenever I try to create an offscreen canvas from my canvas I always get:

```
Failed to execute 'transferControlToOffscreen' on 
'HTMLCanvasElement': Cannot transfer control from a canvas that has a rendering context.
```

As I said, I am just trying to figure out how to render my animation smoothly but am not sure how to go about it. Any help here would be great. Here is the code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="render">Render</button>
    <h2>Backgrounds</h2>
    <template v-for="background in backgrounds">
      <img
        :src="background.poster"
        class="backgrounds"
        @click="changeBackground(background.video)"
      />
    </template>
    <h2>Images</h2>
    <template v-for="image in images">
      <img
        :src="image.source"
        @click="addImage(image)"
        class="images"
      />
    </template>
    <br />
    <button @click="addText">Add Text</button>
    <button v-if="selectedNode" @click="removeNode">
      Remove selected {{ selectedNode.type }}
    </button>
    <label>Font:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFont">
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
      <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Desoto">Desoto</option>
      <option value="Kalam">Kalam</option>
    </select>
    <label>Font Size</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="selectedFontSize" />
    <label>Font Style:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFontStyle">
      <option value="normal">Normal</option>
      <option value="bold">Bold</option>
      <option value="italic">Italic</option>
    </select>
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="color" v-model="selectedColor" />
    <button
      v-if="selectedNode && selectedNode.type === 'text'"
      @click="updateText"
    >
      Update Text
    </button>
    <template v-if="selectedNode && selectedNode.lottie">
    <input type="text" v-model="text">
    <button @click="updateAnim(selectedNode.image)">
      Update Animation
    </button>
    </template>
    <br />
    <video
      id="preview"
      v-show="preview"
      :src="preview"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      preload="auto"
      controls
    />
    <a v-if="file" :href="file" download="dopeness.mp4">download</a>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import lottie from "lottie-web";
import * as anim from "../AEAnim/anim.json";
import * as anim2 from "../AEAnim/anim2.json";
import * as anim3 from "../AEAnim/anim3.json";
import * as anim4 from "../AEAnim/anim4.json";
import * as anim5 from "../AEAnim/anim5.json";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      source: null,
      stage: null,
      layer: null,
      video: null,
      animations: [],
      text: "",
      animationData: null,
      captures: [],
      backgrounds: [
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/main/1080/3oref310k1uud86w_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/main/1080/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/2ez931ik1mggd6j/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/2ez931ik1mggd6j/main/1080/2ez931ik1mggd6j_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15/main/1080/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster:
            "https://images.costco-static.com/ImageDelivery/imageService?profileId=12026540&itemId=100424771-847&recipeName=680",
          video: "/api/files/jedi/surfing.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster:
            "https://thedefensepost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/us-soldiers-afghanistan-4308413-1170x610.jpg",
          video: "/api/files/jedi/soldiers.mp4"
        }
      ],
      images: [
        { source: "/api/files/jedi/solo.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yoda.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yodaChristmas.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/darthMaul.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/darthMaul1.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/trump.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/hat.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/trump.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/bernie.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/skywalker.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/vader.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/vader2.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yoda.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/kylo.gif" },
        {
          source: "https://media3.giphy.com/media/R3IxJW14a3QNa/source.gif",
          animation: anim
        },
        {
        source: "https://bestanimations.com/Text/Cool/cool-story-3.gif",
        animation: anim2
        },
        {
          source: "https://freefrontend.com/assets/img/css-text-animations/HTML-CSS-Animated-Text-Fill.gif",
          animation: anim3
        },
        {
          source: "api/files/jedi/zoomer.gif",
          animation: anim4
        },
        {
          source: "api/files/jedi/slider.gif",
          animation: anim5
        }
      ],
      backgroundVideo: null,
      imageGroups: [],
      anim: null,
      selectedNode: null,
      selectedFont: "Arial",
      selectedColor: "black",
      selectedFontSize: 20,
      selectedFontStyle: "normal",
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      texts: [],
      preview: null,
      file: null,
      canvas: null
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.initCanvas();
  },
  methods: {
    changeBackground(source) {
      this.source = source;
      this.video.src = this.source;
      this.anim.stop();
      this.anim.start();
      this.video.play();
    },
    removeNode() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        this.selectedNode.transformer.destroy(
          this.selectedNode.text.transformer
        );
        this.selectedNode.text.destroy(this.selectedNode.text);
        this.texts.splice(this.selectedNode.text.index - 1, 1);
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      } else if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type == "image") {
        this.selectedNode.group.destroy(this.selectedNode);
        this.imageGroups.splice(this.selectedNode.group.index - 1, 1);
        if (this.selectedNode.lottie) {
          clearTimeout(this.animations.interval);
          this.selectedNode.lottie.destroy();
          this.animations.splice(this.selectedNode.lottie.index - 1, 1);
        }
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    async addImage(imageToAdd, isUpdate) {
      let lottieAnimation = null;
      let imageObj = null;
      const type = imageToAdd.source.slice(imageToAdd.source.lastIndexOf("."));
      const vm = this;
      function process(img) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          img.onload = () => resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
        });
      }
      imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.src = imageToAdd.source;
      imageObj.width = 200;
      imageObj.height = 200;
      await process(imageObj);

      if (type === ".gif" && !imageToAdd.animation) {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "gif");
        async function onDrawFrame(ctx, frame) {
          ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, frame.x, frame.y);
          // redraw the layer
          vm.layer.draw();
        }
        gifler(imageToAdd.source).frames(canvas, onDrawFrame);

        canvas.onload = async () => {
          canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
        };
        imageObj = canvas;
        const gif = new Image();
        gif.src = imageToAdd.source;
        const gifImage = await process(gif);
        imageObj.width = gifImage.width;
        imageObj.height = gifImage.height;
      } else if (imageToAdd.animation) {
        if(!isUpdate){this.text = "new text";}
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.width = 1920;
        canvas.style.height= 1080;
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "animationCanvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "animationContainer");
        div.style.display = "none";
        canvas.style.display = "none";
        this.animationData = imageToAdd.animation.default;
        for(let i =0; i <this.animationData.layers.length; i++){
          for(let b =0; b<this.animationData.layers[i].t.d.k.length; b++){
            this.animationData.layers[i].t.d.k[b].s.t = this.text;
          }
        }
         lottieAnimation = lottie.loadAnimation({
          container: div, // the dom element that will contain the animation
          renderer: "svg",
          loop: true,
          autoplay: true,
          animationData: this.animationData
        });
        lottieAnimation.imgSrc = imageToAdd.source;
        lottieAnimation.text = this.text;
        const svg = await div.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
        const timer = setInterval(async () => {

          const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
          const svg64 = window.btoa(xml);
          const b64Start = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
          const image64 = b64Start + svg64;
          imageObj = new Image({ width: canvas.width, height: canvas.height });
          imageObj.src = image64;
          await process(imageObj);
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
           this.layer.batchDraw();
        }, 1000 / 30);
        this.animations.push({ lottie: lottieAnimation, interval: timer });
        imageObj = canvas;
        canvas.onload = async () => {
          canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
        };
      }
      const image = new Konva.Image({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        width: imageObj.width,
        height: imageObj.height,
        position: (0, 0),
        strokeWidth: 10,
        stroke: "blue",
        strokeEnabled: false
      });

      const group = new Konva.Group({
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      addAnchor(group, 0, 0, "topLeft");
      addAnchor(group, imageObj.width, 0, "topRight");
      addAnchor(group, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, "bottomRight");
      addAnchor(group, 0, imageObj.height, "bottomLeft");
      imageObj = null;
      image.on("click", function () {
        vm.hideAllHelpers();
        vm.selectedNode = {
          type: "image",
          group,
          lottie: lottieAnimation,
          image: imageToAdd
        };
        if(lottieAnimation && lottieAnimation.text){vm.text = lottieAnimation.text}
        group.find("Circle").show();

        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      image.on("mouseover", function(evt) {
        if (vm.selectedNode && vm.selectedNode.type === "image") {
          const index = image.getParent().index;
          const groupId = vm.selectedNode.group.index;
          if (index != groupId) {
            evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
            vm.layer.draw();
          }
        } else {
          evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
          vm.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      image.on("mouseout", function(evt) {
        evt.target.strokeEnabled(false);
        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      vm.hideAllHelpers();
      group.find("Circle").show();
      group.add(image);
      vm.layer.add(group);
      vm.imageGroups.push(group);

      vm.selectedNode = {
        type: "image",
        group,
        lottie: lottieAnimation,
        image: imageToAdd
      };
      function update(activeAnchor) {
        const group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        let topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0];
        let topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0];
        let bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0];
        let bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0];
        let image = group.get("Image")[0];

        let anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        let anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case "topLeft":
            topRight.y(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "topRight":
            topLeft.y(anchorY);
            bottomRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomRight":
            bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
            topRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomLeft":
            bottomRight.y(anchorY);
            topLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());

        let width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        let height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height) {
          image.width(width);
          image.height(height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        let stage = vm.stage;
        let layer = vm.layer;

        let anchor = new Konva.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
          group.draggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on("dragend", function() {
          group.draggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.strokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
    },
    async updateAnim(image){
     this.addImage(image, true);
      this.removeNode();

    },
    hideAllHelpers() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
        this.texts[i].transformer.hide();
      }
      for (let b = 0; b < this.imageGroups.length; b++) {
        this.imageGroups[b].find("Circle").hide();
      }
    },
    async startRecording(duration) {
      const chunks = []; // here we will store our recorded media chunks (Blobs)
      const stream = this.canvas.captureStream(30); // grab our canvas MediaStream
      const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        videoBitsPerSecond: 20000 * 1000
      });
      // every time the recorder has new data, we will store it in our array
      rec.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
      // only when the recorder stops, we construct a complete Blob from all the chunks
      rec.onstop = async e => {
        this.anim.stop();

        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
          type: "video/webm"
        });

        this.preview = await URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const video = window.document.getElementById("preview");
        const previewVideo = new Konva.Image({
          image: video,
          draggable: false,
          width: this.width,
          height: this.height
        });
        this.layer.add(previewVideo);

        console.log("video", video);
        video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
          console.log("preview ended");
          if (!this.file) {
            const vid = new Whammy.fromImageArray(this.captures, 30);
            this.file = URL.createObjectURL(vid);
          }
          previewVideo.destroy();
          this.anim.stop();
          this.anim.start();
          this.video.play();
        });
        let seekResolve;

        video.addEventListener("seeked", async () => {
          if (seekResolve) seekResolve();
        });
        video.addEventListener("loadeddata", async () => {
          let interval = 1 / 30;
          let currentTime = 0;
          while (currentTime <= duration && !this.file) {
            video.currentTime = currentTime;
            await new Promise(r => (seekResolve = r));

            this.layer.draw();
            let base64ImageData = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
            this.captures.push(base64ImageData);
            currentTime += interval;
            video.currentTime = currentTime;
          }

          this.layer.draw();
        });
      };
      rec.start();
      setTimeout(() => rec.stop(), duration);
    },
    async render() {
      this.captures = [];
      this.preview = null;
      this.file = null;
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = null;
      this.video.currentTime = 0;
      this.video.loop = false;
      const duration = this.video.duration * 1000;
      this.startRecording(duration);
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    updateText() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        const text = this.selectedNode.text;
        const transformer = this.selectedNode.transformer;
        text.fontSize(this.selectedFontSize);
        text.fontFamily(this.selectedFont);
        text.fontStyle(this.selectedFontStyle);
        text.fill(this.selectedColor);
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    addText() {
      const vm = this;
      const text = new Konva.Text({
        text: "new text " + (vm.texts.length + 1),
        x: 50,
        y: 80,
        fontSize: this.selectedFontSize,
        fontFamily: this.selectedFont,
        fontStyle: this.selectedFontStyle,
        fill: this.selectedColor,
        align: "center",
        width: this.width * 0.5,
        draggable: true
      });
      const transformer = new Konva.Transformer({
        node: text,
        keepRatio: true,
        enabledAnchors: ["top-left", "top-right", "bottom-left", "bottom-right"]
      });
      text.on("click", async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
          let item = this.texts[i];
          if (item.index === text.index) {
            let transformer = item.transformer;
            this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
            this.selectedFontSize = text.fontSize();
            this.selectedFont = text.fontFamily();
            this.selectedFontStyle = text.fontStyle();
            this.selectedColor = text.fill();
            vm.hideAllHelpers();
            transformer.show();
            transformer.moveToTop();
            text.moveToTop();
            vm.layer.draw();
            break;
          }
        }
      });
      text.on("mouseover", () => {
        transformer.show();
        this.layer.draw();
      });
      text.on("mouseout", () => {
        if (
          (this.selectedNode &&
            this.selectedNode.text &&
            this.selectedNode.text.index != text.index) ||
          (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "image") ||
          !this.selectedNode
        ) {
          transformer.hide();
          this.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      text.on("dblclick", () => {
        text.hide();
        transformer.hide();
        vm.layer.draw();
        let textPosition = text.absolutePosition();

        let stageBox = vm.stage.container().getBoundingClientRect();

        let areaPosition = {
          x: stageBox.left + textPosition.x,
          y: stageBox.top + textPosition.y
        };

        let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        window.document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.value = text.text();
        textarea.style.position = "absolute";
        textarea.style.top = areaPosition.y + "px";
        textarea.style.left = areaPosition.x + "px";
        textarea.style.width = text.width() - text.padding() * 2 + "px";
        textarea.style.height = text.height() - text.padding() * 2 + 5 + "px";
        textarea.style.fontSize = text.fontSize() + "px";
        textarea.style.border = "none";
        textarea.style.padding = "0px";
        textarea.style.margin = "0px";
        textarea.style.overflow = "hidden";
        textarea.style.background = "none";
        textarea.style.outline = "none";
        textarea.style.resize = "none";
        textarea.style.lineHeight = text.lineHeight();
        textarea.style.fontFamily = text.fontFamily();
        textarea.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
        textarea.style.textAlign = text.align();
        textarea.style.color = text.fill();
        let rotation = text.rotation();
        let transform = "";
        if (rotation) {
          transform += "rotateZ(" + rotation + "deg)";
        }
        let px = 0;
        let isFirefox =
          navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
        if (isFirefox) {
          px += 2 + Math.round(text.fontSize() / 20);
        }
        transform += "translateY(-" + px + "px)";
        textarea.style.transform = transform;
        textarea.style.height = "auto";
        textarea.focus();

        // start
        function removeTextarea() {
          textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
          window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
          text.show();
          transformer.show();
          transformer.forceUpdate();
          vm.layer.draw();
        }

        function setTextareaWidth(newWidth) {
          if (!newWidth) {
            // set width for placeholder
            newWidth = text.placeholder.length * text.fontSize();
          }
          // some extra fixes on different browsers
          let isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent
          );
          let isFirefox =
            navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
          if (isSafari || isFirefox) {
            newWidth = Math.ceil(newWidth);
          }

          let isEdge =
            document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent);
          if (isEdge) {
            newWidth += 1;
          }
          textarea.style.width = newWidth + "px";
        }

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          // hide on enter
          // but don't hide on shift + enter
          if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
          // on esc do not set value back to node
          if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            removeTextarea();
          }
        });

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          let scale = text.getAbsoluteScale().x;
          setTextareaWidth(text.width() * scale);
          textarea.style.height = "auto";
          textarea.style.height =
            textarea.scrollHeight + text.fontSize() + "px";
        });

        function handleOutsideClick(e) {
          if (e.target !== textarea) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
        });
        // end
      });
      text.transformer = transformer;
      this.texts.push(text);
      this.layer.add(text);
      this.layer.add(transformer);
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
      transformer.show();
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    initCanvas() {
      const vm = this;
      this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: vm.width,
        height: vm.height
      });
      this.layer = new Konva.Layer();
      this.stage.add(this.layer);

      let video = document.createElement("video");
      video.setAttribute("id", "video");
      video.setAttribute("ref", "video");
      if (this.source) {
        video.src = this.source;
      }
      video.preload = "auto";
      video.loop = "loop";
      video.style.display = "none";
      this.video = video;
      this.backgroundVideo = new Konva.Image({
        image: vm.video,
        draggable: false
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
        vm.backgroundVideo.width(vm.width);
        vm.backgroundVideo.height(vm.height);
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        console.log("the video ended");
        this.anim.stop();
        this.anim.start();
        this.video.loop = "loop";
        this.video.play();
      });

      this.anim = new Konva.Animation(function() {
        console.log("animation called");
        // do nothing, animation just need to update the layer
      }, vm.layer);

      this.layer.add(this.backgroundVideo);
      this.layer.batchDraw();
      const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      canvas.style.border = "3px solid red";
      this.canvas = canvas;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.backgrounds,
.images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: There are different strategies you can apply when working with the Offscreen Canvas. What sources have you read so far? And can you add an isolated code snippet that  shows what you are trying to make but throws that error.
Also, I learned a lot from reading this article about the Offscreen Canvas. Maybe it can help you get started (if you haven't read it yet of course): https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/13092-javascript-canvas-offscreencanvas.html

Comment: @Wezelkrozum, here is my code underneath this.canvas = canvas; in the init canvas function I was doing const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen(); and this is what was failing. Thank you for the link I've been reading it. I hope this gives you some context as to what I am talking about. If you can think of a simple way to speed this up let me know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### About the error message

Just like you can't request a context 'B' after you got a context 'A', you can't transfer a DOM canvas's control to an OffscreenCanvas after you did request a context from that canvas.

Here you are using Konva.js library (that I don't particularly know) to initialize your DOM canvas. This library will need to access one of the available contexts (apparently the "2D" one) from that canvas. This means that when you will gain access to that canvas, a context will already have been requested by the library and that you won't be able to transfer its control to an OffscreenCanvas.

There is [this issue](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/446) on the library's repo, which points out that no later than 12 days ago they added some initial support for OffscreenCanvases. So I invite you to look at [their example](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Web_Worker.html) on how to proceed with that library.

---

#### About OffscreenCanvas Performances

An OffscreenCanvas in itself **doesn't offer any performance boost** compared to a regular canvas. It won't magically make your code that was running at 10FPS to run at 60FPS.
What it allows is to **not block the main thread**, and to **not be blocked by the main thread**. And for this, you need to transfer it to a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).

This means you may use it

- if you are afraid your canvas code can block the UI but you don't really require smooth animation always.
- if you are afraid your main thread may slow down your canvas animation - e.g if you have a lot of other stuff going on on the page.

But in your case, it seems that there is only your code running. So you will probably not win anything by going this route.

---

#### About OffscreenCanvas limitations

We saw that to really take advantages of an OffscreenCanvas, we need to run it in a parallel thread from a Web Worker. But **Web Workers don't have access to the DOM.**
This is a *huge* limitation and will make a lot of things way more harder to handle.

For instance, to draw your video, you currently have no other way than to use a `<video>` element to play it first. The Worker script can't access that `<video>` element, and it can't create one on its own thread. So the only solution is to create an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) **from the main thread** and to pass it back to your Worker script.
**All the hard work (video decoding + bitmap generation) is done on the main thread.** It is worth noting that even though the `createImageBitmap()` method returns a Promise, when we use a video as source, the browser has no other choice than to create the Bitmap from the video **synchronously**.
So while getting that ImageBitmap for use in your worker, you are actually overloading the main thread, and if the main thread is locked doing something else, you will obviously have to wait it's done before getting your frame from the video.

***2021 update:** [The WebCodecs API](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/) has made a lot of progress, and it is now possible (in Chrome) to use a [VideoDecoder](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#videodecoder-interface) from a DedicatedWorker directly, it should also be possible to transfer [VideoFrames](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#videoframe-interface) from the main thread to the Worker thread to be drawn on the OffscreenCanvas, and in a near future we should even be able to transfer ReadableStreams from MediaStreamTracks to a Worker directly, all this is still quite experimental, but when available, it's far better than <video> + ImageBitmap.*

An other big limitation is that currently* Web Workers can't react to DOM events. So you have to set up a proxy to pass the events received in the main thread to your Worker thread. Once again this requires your main thread to be free and a lot of new code.

---

#### About your code

Because, yeah, I believe this is where you should be looking if you want performance improvements.

I only gave it a quick look, but I already saw that you are using `setInterval` in a few places at high rate. Don't. If you need to animate something visible always use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), if you don't need the full speed, then add an inner logic to skip frames, but keep using rAF as the main engine.

You are asking the browser to do heavy actions every frames. For instance your svg part is creating a full new svg markup from the DOM node at every frame, then this markup is loaded in an `<img>` (this mean the browser has to launch an entire new DOM for that image), and rasterized on a canvas.
This in itself will be hard to cope at high frame-rate, and an OffscreenCanvas won't help.

You are storing all the images as stills to produce your final video. This will take a lot of memory.

There is probably a lot of other stuff like that in your code, so review it thoroughly and search for what make your code not able to reach the screen refresh rate. Improve what can be, search for alternatives (for instance MediaRecorder might be better than Whammy when supported) and good luck.

---

*<sup>There is an [ongoing proposal](https://github.com/WICG/input-for-workers) to fix that issue</sup>

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your advice. Two questions to follow up with that: 1. I am trying to use requestAnimationFrame to update one of the setIntervals but it doesn't seem to be working. Although I get no errors. I know this is a huge favor but any chance you could give me an example? 2. With the SVG to createImageBitmap does it matter that my svg is animated? I mean when I create a bitmap isn't it pretty static? It is not updating the image data as the svg moves correct? If this is the case do you have any other suggestions for the svg?

Comment: @codernoob8 1. requestAnimationFrame schedules a single event, so you need to call it recursively in the callback (it's just like a `setTimeout( cb, time_until_next_screen_refresh  )`). 2. Sorry I didn't got that you were drawing *animated* svgs. In that case you indeed need to rebuild them every frames... except if you have a way to convert these animations to canvas path drawings. But anyway, here an OffscreenCanvas will not help at all either.

Comment: According to this article, OffscreenCanvas *does* offer (some) performance improvements, even when used without a Worker (although a regular canvas that isn't in the DOM may benefit from (most of) the same improvements?): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/offscreen-canvas#:~:text=The%20OffscreenCanvas%20allows%20to%20create,browser%20does%20not%20support%20OffscreenCanvas.

Comment: 1/2 @REJH that claim is kinda weird to be honest. Let's note it was written in 2018, and many things have changed since then. That being said, I don't understand where they see having the rendering tied to the DOM would cause any performance hit on the rendering. My best bet is that they implied that *normal* canvases rendering happens as part of the "update the rendering" steps of the Event loop. This may indeed cause some delay between the input and the actual rendering. But since then, *normal* canvases' contexts won a `desynchronized` attribute, which fixes this, while OffscreenCanvases...

Comment: 2/2 ...did lose their `commit()` method and thus have their rendering completely dependent on this "update the rendering" step of the Event Loop. So... in this regard a *normal* canvas can actually be *more* performant. Now, I'm really not sure it's what they were talking about, but if not, I have no clue what it is...

Comment: Yeah I think when they announced offscr canvas, the normal canvas was tied to the render steps (so render/paint), which takes some of the 16ms budget. Offscreen canvas fixes that, but I don't see how a unattached canvas wouldn't have the same benefit. I've done some testing since my comment and while drawing *may* be a little faster, transferring the bitmap from offscreen to real canvas using transferToImageBitmap can take up to ~20 ms (on a Surface Laptop 3 on battery) so.. that defeats the whole purpose :P

Comment: If you only want to render that offscreen canvas, *transferControlToOffscreen* one from a <canvas>. Also, my point is that an OffscreenCanvas **is** tied to the render loop, even more than a normal canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but one important correction. These days the following isn't true - "So the only solution is to create an ImageBitmap from the main thread and to pass it back to your Worker script." Because Blobs are structured clonable, they can be passed from the main thread to the worker, and workers have access to `self.createImageBitmap(myBloborFile)` for doing the work of converting the file to a bitmap. Anecdotally, I've seen some significant performance benefits in taking this approach in specific applications

Comment: @NeilVanLandingham I was specifically talking about <video>. There is actually now a way through the incoming [WebCodecs API](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#videoframe-interface), since VideoFrames should be tranferables, but I think the worker side is not yet really usable as of today. (though I'll probably add a note about it when I get time.)